# How to avoid large amounts of queries when fetching doctrine relational entities

Tags: sql, performance, symfony, doctrine

I never paid much attention to the number of queries generated by doctrine, until today when I got a fairly simple task (or so I thought) running 750 queries for 16 seconds...

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->em;

    $risks = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Risk')->findAll();

    //filter out only risks belonging to a current version analysis
    $risksCurrent = array();

    foreach($risks as $r) {
        if ($r->getAnalysis()->getCurrentVersion() == true) {
            $risksCurrent[] = $r;
        }               
    }

    return $this->render('risk/index.html.twig', array(
        'risks' => $risksCurrent,
    ));
}
```

So I suppose for each turn in the loop a new SQL query is executed. I thought the objects were fetched in their entirety upon first call, and then it didn't "cost" me a DB call to access properties on those objects, but sorely mistaken I was =)

Is there a way to do this more efficiently without resorting to writing good old SQL queries? I can do it by

```
SELECT * FROM risk JOIN analysis ON risk.analysis = analysis.id WHERE (analysis.CurrentVersion = true)
```

But I would rather deal with the entity objects than SQL...

---

Changing the controller to...

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->em;

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT * FROM risk JOIN analysis ON risk.analysis = analysis.id WHERE (analysis.CurrentVersion = true)');
    $risksCurrent = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('risk/index.html.twig', array(
        'risks' => $risksCurrent,
    ));
}
```

... got it down to 18 queries in half a second which is a lot more comfortable... still I only see one single query there in my code so I don't know what's going on with that

Comment: Doctrine doesn't fully hydrate all related entities until they are called upon (which is what you do in the foreach loop). I recommend [this symfonycasts lesson](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/join-n-plus-one) on the `N+1` problem. There are other resources as well.

Comment: Whether or not doctrine fetches all the related objects _by default_ depends on the [`fetch` mode`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) set in each association in your entity (and not all relation types support the same modes). Although it might be useful, generally speaking would be better to rely on custom queries in the repository when you when you need to explicitly join, specially if you need extra conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine is by default not querying the relations and is fetching them only when it needs them. When your scenario with many same queries happens, it is called the `N+1 problem`. Here are two basic solution how to avoid this problem.

## Solution 1 – configure fetching via mapping

This solution is only good when you know you need your `Analysis` **always** with your `Risk`. If you have for example page with `Risk` detail, where you don't need to access `Analysis` this solution might not be the best.

For example imagine this entity:

```php
class Risk
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Analysis::class)
     */
    private $analysis;

    ...
}
```

Right now, if you would execute your code it would have the same problem. But if you add `fetch="EAGER"`, Doctrine will fetch all Analysis in advance in one query.

Your entity would now look like this:

```php
class Risk
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Analysis::class, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $analysis;

    ...
}
```

## Solution 2 – use repository and Doctrine Query Builder with `join`

In this solution you might create custom method in your Repository, where you will join your relations. Also it would be a good idea to filter only current Analysis right away. The repository might look like this:

```php
class RiskRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    ...

    /**
     * @return Risk[]
     */
    public function findAllWithCurrentAnalysis(): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('risk')
            ->addSelect('analysis')
            ->join('risk.analysis', 'analysis')
            ->andWhere('analysis.currentVersion = :true')
            ->setParameter('true', true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    ...
}
```

Your Controller action would then look like this:

```php
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->em;

    $risks = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Risk')->findAllWithCurrentAnalysis();

    return $this->render('risk/index.html.twig', array(
        'risks' => $risks,
    ));
}
```